# SPARQL query of Turtle data returns no rows when using skos:prefLabel

Tags: sparql, pubchem

I'm trying to query PubChem disease data from their Turtle file in GraphDb.  The standard query returns all the `?s` `?p` `?o` rows as expected.  But I just want the `?s` and `skos:prefLabel`.

Example disease data: https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/rdf/disease/DZID8805.html

This returns 100 rows as expected. One row shown below.

```
select * 
FROM <http://localhost:7200/diseases>  
where { 
   ?s ?p ?o .
} limit 100
```

> disease:DZID1364  /  rdf:type  /  obo:DOID_4

I tried various queries with no results. This is the latest attempt. It's from a named graph that contains all the data locally.  I'm new to SPARQL and RDF and this just looks like it should work.

```
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#/>  
prefix disease: <http://rdf.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubchem/disease/>

SELECT ?label
FROM <http://localhost:7200/diseases>  
WHERE { 
    ?disease skos:prefLabel ?label
} limit 100
```

Expected row below.

> disease:DZID1364  /  White platelet syndrome

From TTL file:

```
disease:DZID1364  skos:prefLabel  "White platelet syndrome" .
```

Comment: your `skos:` prefix declaration is broken. Remove the trailing `/` - it's usually either `#` or `/`, but not both. In the SKOS case it is a trailing `#`

Comment: @UninformedUser that did it!  I'll keep that in mind going forward. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @UninformedUser, I removed the trailing / from the skos prefix declaration and it resolved the issue.